# Basic mmap(2) call fails

Tags: c, linux, mmap

I've been pulling my hairs out for hours on this very basic piece of code and I haven't managed to understand why mmap(2) was failing.

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NPAGES      50
#define SLABSIZE    (PAGE_SIZE * NPAGES)      // 200 kB

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char *slab;

        printf("DEBUG: mmap(%#x, %u, %#x, %#x, %d, %u)\n",
            NULL, SLABSIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
        slab = mmap(NULL, SLABSIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
        if (slab == MAP_FAILED)
                err(1, "mmap");
}
```

But when I run it:

```
$ make mmap
cc     mmap.c   -o mmap
$ ./mmap 
DEBUG: mmap(0, 204800, 0x3, 0x20, -1, 0)
mmap: mmap: Invalid argument
```

I checked and re-checked mmap(2)'s manpage [1], and it seems that all requirements are OK but I must be missing something.
I'm running Linux kernel 4.8.13.

Thanks.
-- Jeremie

[1] http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

Comment: `MAP_ANON` is deprecated. What are you trying to achieve? If you want to map it across processes use `MAP_SHARED`

Comment: Both are orthogonal. MAP_ANON(YMOUS) just tells to back the region with swappable memory.  MAP_SHARED says this mapping can be shared with other processes.

Answer (score 5):

When `strace` ing your program, I see:

> mmap(NULL, 204800, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_FILE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)

You forgot a `MAP_SHARED` flag (or a `MAP_PRIVATE` one). With it (either `MAP_SHARED` or `MAP_PRIVATE`, but you need one of them) your program works:

```
    slab = mmap(NULL, SLABSIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
```

Quoting the [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) man page:

> This behavior is determined by including ***exactly* one of the following** values in flags:

<sup>(emphasis is mine)</sup>

> ```
>   MAP_SHARED
>           Share this mapping.  Updates to the mapping are visible to
>           other processes mapping the same region, and (in the case of
>           file-backed mappings) are carried through to the underlying
>           file.  (To precisely control when updates are carried through
>           to the underlying file requires the use of msync(2).)
>
>   MAP_PRIVATE
>           Create a private copy-on-write mapping.  Updates to the
>           mapping are not visible to other processes mapping the same
>           file, and are not carried through to the underlying file.  It
>           is unspecified whether changes made to the file after the
>           mmap() call are visible in the mapped region.
> ```

So the general advice before pulling your hairs: read once again the documentation; take a nap; read another time the documentation and think about what did you miss.

Another hint would be to use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on some (or several) *existing* executable(s). You'll learn a lot.